# My array printf loop is missing one digit at the end

Tags: c, arrays, missing-data

I'm trying to convert decimal to binary via this program, but the output is always missing the last digit.

For example, I'll input "123" for ***quotient***, and the result will be "111101" instead of "1111011". This happens for every input I test. Every digit is in the right place, except for the last one, which is missing.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int quotient = 123;
    int i = 0;
    int d1 = quotient % 2;
    quotient = quotient / 2;
    int c = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int number[32] = {};

    while (quotient != 0)
    {
        i = i+1;
        d1 = quotient % 2;
        quotient = quotient / 2;
        c++;
        number[c]=d1;
    }

    for(a = 0; a < c; a = a + 1 )
    {
        printf("%d", number[c-a]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're incrementing `c` before you store, so the first result is stored in `number[1]`, not `number[0]`

Comment: Nicely written question, thank you. Has everything needed to be answerable, but not too much.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I edited the question already ... waiting for the accept

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName: One more to go...

Comment: The only variable who’s purpose I can understand is ` quotient `. I assure you, the same will be true for you in 6 months time. Get into the habit of writing maintainable code, which means at least meaningful variable names, with comments where necessary.

Comment: Also, get an IDE with a debugger (MS Visual Studio, Eclipse CDT, Code::Blocks, Netbeans, etc) and learn how to use it. It is your single most useful tool. With a debugger, you can set a “breakpoint” on alien of code and run until it is reached; then the debugger will stop and you can step through your code, line by line, examining the values of variables as you go. If you gad use da debugger, you would not have needed to post this question and could have saved yourself much time which you will now spend waiting for an answer.

Comment: The issue is occurring because you manipulate `quotient` before the loop, but do not include that initial manipulation in your results.  You're effectively throwing away that result.  (If you start with `int quotient = 1`, your while loop is never executed)

Comment: additionally : be aware that your code won't work as expected for values <= 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're dividing once before the `while` loop :

```
int d1 = quotient % 2;
quotient = quotient / 2;
```

Replace that with just :

```
int d1 = 0;
```

and things should work better.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following problems in your code

1. should be handled in while loop.

   `int d1 = quotient % 2;
     quotient = quotient / 2;`
2. You are incrementing the `c` before putting into the array.
3. Your printf is wrong  `printf("%d", number[c-a]);` should be  `printf("%d", number[c-a-1]);`

Your full code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
  int quotient = 15;
  int i = 0;
  int d1;
  //quotient = quotient / 2;
  int c = 0;
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;
  int number[32] = {};

  while (quotient != 0){
     d1 = quotient % 2;
     quotient = quotient / 2;
     number[c]=d1;
    printf("%d\n", number[c]);
     c++;
  }
  for(a = 0; a < c; a = a + 1 ){
    printf("%d", number[c-a-1]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```